# UBER API drivers di

Tags: uber-api

I am wondering whether we can use UBER API to figure out the number of drivers for a given location.

Our Need is to figure out the loaded areas where we have more people than others. To this end, we thought on different apps among them UBER which can also give an idea on how many people are on a given location.

Any help whether the UBER API can provide such information with exact location (longitude latitude). Our need, in terms of data, is to have a dataset for different exact locations showing the exact live ocation of drivers for a given city on a specific period of time.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not available. Please see the docs here for the 3 endpoints on the driver API (none of which provide real-time availability / location): https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/introduction